# How do I use React Developer Tool's "open in editor" functionality?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, react-developer-tools

[image: config panel]

OK let's say I have it configured with the default. How do I then open a component from the components tree in my editor?

There's nothing on the right click menu:

[image: right click menu]

If you hover over all the icons on the right side none of them are anything like "open in editor":

[image: right side panel]

The eyeball is the obvious choice but it just goes to the Elements tab in Chrome.

How do I actually use "Open in Editor"? There's no documentation [that I can find](https://www.google.com/search?q=react%20developer%20tools%20%22Open%20in%20Editor%22%20how) about it.

Comment: You can try https://github.com/ericclemmons/click-to-component

Comment: @code It only works locally.

Answer (score -1):

[This comment](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/25344#issuecomment-1262852599) shows the button location.  On my machine, it looks like:

[image: Arrow pointing to the "Open in Editor" icon in React DevTools]

I noticed that the button did not appear until I configured "Open in Editor URL," but it appears that you've done so.  It looks like you have curly braces around `file`, which I'm not sure is correct.  Nevertheless, those curly braces don't stop the button from appearing for me.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem and figured out that "open in editor" only works in `StrictMode`

Comment: This could use some clarification. Where is StrictMode set?